# If $g$ is in group $G$, then $g$ belongs to a subgroup $H$ only if $gH = H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have tried to prove this but I am unable to proceed. I have been successful in proving that $gH = H \implies g \in H$ but I am unable to prove the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although unclear, I am assuming that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Assuming that $g \in H$, as $gh \in H$ is true whenever $h \in H$ implies that $gH \subset H$. Now, for any $h \in H$, we can write it as $h = gg^{-1}h$, and since $g^{-1}h \in H$, it implies that $h \in gH$ and thus $H \subset gH$. Conversely, assuming $gH = H$ to be true implies that $ge \in H$ which further implies that $g \in H$.

We can very similarly do it for $Hg = H$ too.

Answer (score 2):

$gH\subseteq H$ because $g\in H$ and $H$ is a subgroup.

On the other hand $H\subseteq gH$ because any element $h\in H$ can be written as $gg^{-1}h$ and $g^{-1}h\in H$, because (again) $g\in H$ and $H$ is a subgroup.